# Program to sum the odd digits recursively

Tags: java, recursion

Using recursion, If `n` is `123`, the code should return `4` (i.e. 1+3). But instead it is returning the last digit, in this case `3`.

```
public static int sumOfOddDigits(NaturalNumber n) {
    int ans = 0;

    if (!n.isZero()) {
        int r = n.divideBy10();
        sumOfOddDigits(n);
        if (r % 2 != 0) {
            ans = ans + r;
        }
        n.multiplyBy10(r);
    }
    return ans;
}
```

Comment: In your own words, when the recursive call `sumOfOddDigits(n);` returns, what do you expect to happen to the result? Why?

Comment: Is it infinity?

Answer (score 2):

It isn't clear what `NaturalNumber` is or why you would prefer it to `int`, but your algorithm is easy enough to follow with `int` (and off). First, you want the remainder (or modulus) of division by `10`. That is the far right digit. Determine if it is odd. If it is add it to the answer, and then when you recurse divide by `10` and make sure to add the result to the answer. Like,

```
public static int sumOfOddDigits(int n) {
    int ans = 0;
    if (n != 0) {
        int r = n % 10;
        if (r % 2 != 0) {
            ans += r;
        }
        ans += sumOfOddDigits(n / 10);
    }
    return ans;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One problem is that you’re calling multiplyBy on n and not doing anything with the result.  NaturalNumber seems likely to be immutable, so the method call has no effect.

But using recursion lets you write declarative code, this kind of imperative logic isn’t needed. instead of mutating local variables you can use the argument list to hold the values to be used in the next iteration:

```
public static int sumOfOddDigits(final int n) {
    return sumOfOddDigits(n, 0);
}

// overload to pass in running total as an argument
public static int sumOfOddDigits(final int n, final int total) {
    // base case: no digits left
    if (n == 0) 
        return total;
    // n is even: check other digits of n
    if (n % 2 == 0) 
        return sumOfOddDigits(n / 10, total);
    // n is odd: add last digit to total, 
    // then check other digits of n
    return sumOfOddDigits(n / 10, n % 10 + total);
}
```

Comment: `final int lastDigit = n % 10;`